# Library to crawl Ajax-based websites fast

Tags: library, java, scraping

I would like to crawl Ajax websites with Java.

I tried Selenium Webdriver and compared to Jsoup for example it is much slower (650ms vs 7.5s).
Since Crawljax is based on Selenium Webdriver I haven't tried it so far.

Do you have any recommendations for a fast Ajax crawler?